# Regular Expression to Read Specifi HTML Rows <TD> PHP

Tags: php, regex

Is there any Regex to Read the  contents from the following Table, note that there are many similar tables so i want only to read the following table contents.

I want to READ All the Rows from Row number `5,6,7 <TR>`

**My regex looks like following but doesnt work**

```
$match = preg_replace('~<tr align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3E4">">GOLD</a></td>#[a-z0-9]{6}~i','',$match[3]);
echo '<table><tr>' . $match . '</tr></table>';
```

MY HTML code looks like this

```
<table width="571" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr bgcolor="#000000"><td><table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="571">

              <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#000000">&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="center" bgcolor="#000000" colspan="8"><p class="white">New 
                    York Spot Price</td>
                <td></td>
                <td align="right" bgcolor="#000000">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr bgcolor="#F3F3E4">
                <td bgcolor="#000000" width="31" nowrap></td>
                <td bgcolor="#000000">&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="center" colspan="7" bgcolor="#F3F3E4"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2"><b><font color=RED>MARKET IS CLOSED</font><BR>(Will open in 5 hrs. 25 mins.)</b></font></td>
                <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3E4">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr bgcolor="#F3F3E4" align="center">
                <td bgcolor="#000000">&nbsp;</td>
                <td bgcolor="#000000">&nbsp;</td>
                <td bgcolor="#CCCC99"><p>Metals</td>
                <td bgcolor="#CCCC99"><p>Date</td>
                <td bgcolor="#CCCC99"><p>Time<br>
                    (EST)</td>
                <td bgcolor="#CCCC99"><p>Bid</td>
                <td bgcolor="#CCCC99"><p>Ask</td>
                <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#CCCC99"><p>Change</td>
                <td bgcolor="#CCCC99"><p>Low</td>
                <td bgcolor="#CCCC99"><p>High</td>
              </tr>
              <tr bgcolor="#F3F3E4" align="center">
                <td bgcolor="#000000" width="31" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
                <td bgcolor="#000000" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="left"><p>&nbsp;<a href="/charts/livegoldnewyork.html" onMouseOver="ChangeImage('NY1','0')" onMouseOut="ChangeImage('NY1','1')">GOLD</a></td>
                <td><p>07/10/2013</td>
                <td><p>17:15</td>
                <td><p>1262.90</td>
                <td><p>1263.90</td>
                <td><p class=spotgreen>+12.20</p></td>
                <td><p class=spotgreen>+0.98%</p></td>
                <td><p>1247.10</td>
                <td><p>1268.40</td>
              </tr>

              <tr align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3E4">
                <td bgcolor="#000000" width="31" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
                <td bgcolor="#000000">&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="left"><p>&nbsp;<a href="/charts/livesilver.html#ny" onMouseOver="ChangeImage('NY2','0')" onMouseOut="ChangeImage('NY2','1')">SILVER</a></td>
                <td><p>07/10/2013</td>
                <td><p>17:15</td>
                <td><p>19.47</td>
                <td><p>19.57</td>
                <td><p class=spotgreen>+0.20</p></td>
                <td bgcolor="#F3F3E4"><p class=spotgreen>+1.06%</p></td>
                <td><p>19.03</td>
                <td><p>19.69</td>
              </tr>
              <tr align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3E4">
                <td bgcolor="#000000" width="31" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
                <td bgcolor="#000000">&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="left"><p>&nbsp;<a href="/charts/liveplatinum.html" onMouseOver="ChangeImage('NY3','0')" onMouseOut="ChangeImage('NY3','1')">PLATINUM</a></td>
                <td><p>07/10/2013</td>
                <td><p>17:13</td>
                <td><p>1372.00</td>
                <td><p>1377.00</td>
                <td><p class=spotgreen>+6.00</p></td>
                <td><p class=spotgreen>+0.44%</p></td>
                <td><p>1358.00</td>
                <td><p>1383.00</td>
              </tr>
              <tr align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3E4">
                <td bgcolor="#000000" width="31" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
                <td bgcolor="#000000">&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="left"><p>&nbsp;<a href="/charts/livepalladium.html" onMouseOver="ChangeImage('NY4','0')" onMouseOut="ChangeImage('NY4','1')">PALLADIUM</a></td>
                <td><p>07/10/2013</td>
                <td><p>17:11</td>
                <td><p>714.00</td>
                <td><p>719.00</td>
                <td><p class=spotgreen>+16.00</p></td>
                <td><p class=spotgreen>+2.29%</p></td>
                <td><p>707.00</td>
                <td><p>721.00</td>
              </tr>
            </table></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1607098)

Comment: Regex everywhere. Sorry, just could not help myself. Regex is not always right tool to solve problems related to strings.

Comment: Hi, this is the third low-quality parsing question that you are asking. Please stop. The link I posted in the deleted question gives you everything you need; [here it is again.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) Also, I notice that your questions are generally of rather low quality. You're asking many things that could be easily looked up in a manual with some effort. Stop being a [help vampire](http://www.slash7.com/pages/vampires) and start helping yourself!

Comment: @Pekka웃 Your comments are offensive i have sent an email to admin@stackoverflow about it, you are acting like that the site is yours

Comment: The questions you are asking here are of consistently rather low quality as far as my cursory check goes. You seem to be using Stack Overflow as a code writing and fixing service. That's not what the place is about.

Comment: I agree @Pekka웃 but if the question is deleted, how is he going to read the link you posted?

Comment: @icedwater he deleted the question himself.

Comment: Ah, well. Can't do anything about it then :)

Comment: btw it's `team@stackoverflow.com` @user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$tr = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr');
$out = array();
foreach ($tr as $key => $value){
    if ($key > 4 && $key < 8){
        $p = $value->getElementsByTagName('p');
        foreach ($p as $key2 => $value2){
            $out[$key][] = $value2->nodeValue;
        }
    }
}
var_dump($out);
```

I got the following:

```
Array
(
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  SILVER
            [1] => 07/10/2013
            [2] => 17:15
            [3] => 19.47
            [4] => 19.57
            [5] => +0.20
            [6] => +1.06%
            [7] => 19.03
            [8] => 19.69
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  PLATINUM
            [1] => 07/10/2013
            [2] => 17:13
            [3] => 1372.00
            [4] => 1377.00
            [5] => +6.00
            [6] => +0.44%
            [7] => 1358.00
            [8] => 1383.00
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  PALLADIUM
            [1] => 07/10/2013
            [2] => 17:11
            [3] => 714.00
            [4] => 719.00
            [5] => +16.00
            [6] => +2.29%
            [7] => 707.00
            [8] => 721.00
        )

)
```

Comment: This is fine code, but is it really necessary to feed a [help vampire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem) on his quest to harvest data from a copyright-protected web site? [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8SyK.jpg) is what he wants to parse

Comment: Stop hiding errors i.e. remove `@`.

Comment: @PédeLeão Sorry for not explaining I thought you could get my point. At development environment you should not hide _any_ error so you could know what's potentially buggy.

Comment: @PLB - I don't usually hide errors, and I hate code that uses @s, but when you are parsing someone else's HTML, sometimes it just makes sense.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - He's not violating copyright law if he's not publishing the data. They are making the data publically available for people to use, and I have no reason to assume that he is going to abuse that privilege.

Comment: Well, their T&C prohibit even that. http://www.kitco.com/TermsofUse/  `All Content supplied by Kitco, constitutes part of Kitco's confidential and proprietary information.  In accessing the Websites or any of the Services, it is strictly prohibited to copy, reproduce, republish, store, retransmit, alter, modify, distribute, make public use thereof, create derivative works from, reverse engineer, disassemble or try to locate source code, of the Content, and any software or applications used by Kitco`

Comment: @Pekka웃 - Did you notice that Kitco's robot.txt file allows robots to access their reports directory?

Comment: @Pé your point being?

Comment: @Pekka웃 - You're trying to prohibit something that they're not.

Comment: Robots.txt settings do not override the Terms and Conditions, which are pretty clear.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - Are you their lawyer? Robots don't read Terms and Conditions. They read robot.txt files. I really don't want to participate in your witch hunt or vampire hunt - whatever you want to call it. If you have a problem with them allowing access in defiance with their terms and conditions, you need to bring that up with Kitco. I'm not going to worry about it.

Comment: Meh. If you want to spend your time answering such questions, be my guest. I just think there's infinitely more interesting and answer-deserving questions on this site.

Comment: Pekka seems to be the lawyer on the internet

Answer (score 0):

I really wonder why you want to use regex for it.
Not sure if you really have to, if so this answer wont be any good for you.
But you can easily solve this problem with jquery.
In jquery you can use `.eq()` function to get this done.

`$('table tr').eq(5).text()`

Made an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/a5Yyf/

Hope its any good to you :) good luck